# how to keep div content and update table contents

Tags: javascript, html

```js
var sum =0 ;
var total=0 ;
var i = 1 ;

function additem ( name , price ) {
    document.getElementById("selecteditems").innerHTML += "<p id='selected"+i+"' >" + name +" :  " + price + " L.E" ;
    
    document.getElementById("removebtn").innerHTML += "<p id='selected"+i+"'>" + "<button id='selected"+i+"' class='btn btn-danger' onclick='removeitem("+i+" , "+price+" ) ' style='font-size: 15px; height: 20px; padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;' >Remove</button> " ;
    i++ ;
    sum += price ;
    }
function removeitem ( i , price ) {
    document.getElementById("selected"+i ).innerHTML= "" ;
    sum -= price ;
    i-- ;
    }

function addclass ( elem ) {
    // get all 'a' elements
    var a = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
    // loop through all 'a' elements
    for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        // Remove the class 'active' if it exists
        a[i].classList.remove('current')  ;
    }
    // add 'active' classs to the element that was clicked
    elem.classList.add('current');
}
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0 px;
    padding: 0px ;
}

ul.topnav {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
    font: bold 15px Tahoma ;
    letter-spacing: 1px ;
}
ul.topnav li {
    float: left;
}
ul.topnav li a{
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.topnav li a.current{
    color: orange ;
    background-color: grey ;
    font-size: large ;
}

table.table-bordered > thead > tr > th{
    border:2px solid black;
}
table.table-bordered > tbody > tr > td{
    border:2px solid pink;
}
#btnl {
    margin: 5px ;
    background-color: red;
}
table td input , table td button {
    font-size: large ;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Restaurant</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
  <script src="js/site.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <img src="2.JPG" alt="Happy Meal" width= "100% ;" height=150px ; >
    </header>
    
    <ul class="topnav">
      <li><a href="#" class="current">Pizza</a></li>
      <li><a href="sandwich.html">Sandwiches</a></li>
      <li><a href="meals.html">Meals</a></li>
      <li><a href="crepe.html">Crepe</a></li>
      <li><a href="salade.html">Salade</a></li>
      <li><a href="about.html">About Us</a></li>
    </ul>
    <section>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <h1 style="margin: 20px 10px 10px 10px ;">Choose Items</h1>
      <div class="row" > 
        <div class="col-md-8" style="background-color: #FAFAFA ;" id="menu">
          <h3 style="margin: 10px 0px 10px 0px ; background-color: #E334CF ; color: white ; font-weight: bold ;">Pizza :</h3>
          <div id="pizza_menu">
            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="text-align: left ; border-color: black;" id="pizza_table">
              <thead style="background-color: #D799F0 ; font: 18px sans-serif ;">
                <tr style="font: bold 22px Tahoma;">
                  <th style="width: 55% ;">Type</th>
                  <th style="width: 15% ;"></th>
                  <th style="width: 15% ;">Price</th>
                  <th style="color: white; font: bold 20px Tahoma ; width: 15% ; text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px black, 0 0 25px blue, 0 0 5px darkblue;">HUNGRY !</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td><h5> Margarita Pizza</h5> <p>Mozzarella cheese, pepper, olives, onion and tomatoes</p> </td>
                  <td>  <img src="image/m.JPG" alt="Margarita" title="Margarita">  </td>
                  <td> <p>small : 20 L.E</p> <P>large : 35 L.E</P> </td>
                  
                  <td>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" style="margin: 5px ;" onclick="additem('Margarita Pizza (S)' , 20 );"> Add Small </button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success"  id="btnl" onclick="additem('Margarita Pizza (L)', 35 );"> Add Large </button>
                  </td> 
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td><h5> Cheese Lovers Pizza  </h5> <p>Mix cheese, pepper, olives, onion and tomatoes</p> </td>
                  <td>  <img src="image/c.jpg" alt="Cheese Lovers" title="Cheese Lovers">  </td>
                  <td> <p>small : 20 L.E</p> <P>large : 35 L.E</P> </td>
                  
                  <td>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" style="margin: 5px ;" onclick="additem('Cheese Lovers (S)', 20 );"> Add Small </button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success"  id="btnl" onclick="additem('Cheese Lovers (L)', 35 )">Add Large</button>
                  </td> 
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td><h5> Vegetables Pizza  </h5> <p>Vegetables, pepper, olives, onion, tomatoes and mozzarella cheese</p> </td>
                  <td>  <img src="image/v.JPG" alt="Vegetables" title="Vegetables">  </td>
                  <td> <p>small : 20 L.E</p> <P>large : 35 L.E</P> </td>
                  
                  <td>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" style="margin: 5px ;" onclick="additem('Vegetables Pizza (S)', 20 );"> Add Small </button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success"  id="btnl" onclick="additem('Vegetables Pizza (L)', 35 );"> Add Large </button>
                  </td> 
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td><h5> Meat Pizza  </h5> <p>Meat, pepper, olives, onion, tomatoes and mozzarella cheese</p> </td>
                  <td>  <img src="image/meat.JPG" alt="Meat" title="Meat">  </td>
                  <td> <p>small : 20 L.E</p> <P>large : 35 L.E</P> </td>
                  
                  <td>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" style="margin: 5px ;" onclick="additem('Meat Pizza (S)', 20 ); ">Add Small</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success"  id="btnl" onclick="additem('Meat Pizza (L)', 35 ); ">Add Large</button>
                  </td> 
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td><h5> Chicken Pizza  </h5> <p>Chicken, chicken pane, pepper, olives, onion, tomatoes and mozzarella cheese</p> </td>
                  <td>  <img src="image/ch.png" alt="Chicken" title="Chicken">  </td>
                  <td> <p>small : 20 L.E</p> <P>large : 35 L.E</P> </td>
                  
                  <td>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" style="margin: 5px ;" onclick="additem('Chicken Pizza (S)', 20 ); ">Add Small</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success"  id="btnl" onclick="additem('Chicken Pizza (L)', 35 ) ;">Add Large</button>
                  </td> 
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td><h5> Mushroom Pizza  </h5> <p>Mushroom, pepper, olives, onion, tomatoes and mozzarella cheese</p> </td>
                  <td>  <img src="image/mu.JPG" alt="Mushroom" title="Mushroom">  </td>
                  <td> <p>small : 20 L.E</p> <P>large : 35 L.E</P> </td>
                  
                  <td>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" style="margin: 5px ;" onclick="additem('Mushroom Pizza (S)', 20 ) ;"> Add Small </button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success"  id="btnl" onclick="additem('Mushroom Pizza (L)', 35 );"> Add Large </button>
                  </td> 
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td><h5>  Seafood Pizza  </h5> <p>Seafood, pepper, olives, onion, tomatoes and mozzarella cheese</p> </td>
                  <td>  <img src="image/s.JPG" alt="Seafood" title="Seafood">  </td>
                  <td> <p>small : 20 L.E</p> <P>large : 35 L.E</P> </td>
                  
                  <td>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" style="margin: 5px ;" onclick="additem('Seafood Pizza (S)', 20 ) ;">Add Small</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="btnl" onclick="additem('Seafood Pizza (L)', 35 ) ;">Add Large</button>
                  </td> 
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md" style="background-color: #D9FFFA; font-size:18px; text-align: left ; margin: 0px 10px 10px 0px" id="order">
          <h1 style="margin-bottom: 10px ; text-align: center ;">Your Order</h1>
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-7" style="margin: 10px 10px;" id="selecteditems">
                
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-3" style="margin: 8px 10px ;" id="removebtn">
                
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </section>

</body>
</html>
```

I am new to web development, this is my second website (online restaurant).
**and I have 3 problems :**

**first :** I want to update the contents of table when the user click a link from navigation bar "topnav" ( the new table may contain different number of rows but last column contains buttons remains ).

**second (may be solution to first) :** if I have to direct to another page that contains different table. how to maintain the details of div "Your Order" (given id="order") . and how to maintain it on reload .

**Third :** in the JS  function additem , when I click button "remove" the details are removed but the button itself not ! , although I give it same id.

any help would be appreciated and thanks in advance.

html :

```
<body>
<header>
    <img src="2.JPG" alt="Happy Meal" width= "100% ;" height=150px ; >
</header>

<ul class="topnav">
  <li><a href="#" class="current">Pizza</a></li>
  <li><a href="sandwich.html">Sandwiches</a></li>
  <li><a href="meals.html">Meals</a></li>
  <li><a href="crepe.html">Crepe</a></li>
  <li><a href="salade.html">Salade</a></li>
  <li><a href="about.html">About Us</a></li>
</ul>
<section>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <h1 style="margin: 20px 10px 10px 10px ;">Choose Items</h1>
  <div class="row" > 
    <div class="col-md-8" style="background-color: #FAFAFA ;" id="menu">
      <h3 style="margin: 10px 0px 10px 0px ; background-color: #E334CF ; color: white ; font-weight: bold ;">Pizza :</h3>
      <div id="pizza_menu">
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="text-align: left ; border-color: black;" id="pizza_table">
          <thead style="background-color: #D799F0 ; font: 18px sans-serif ;">
            <tr style="font: bold 22px Tahoma;">
              <th style="width: 55% ;">Type</th>
              <th style="width: 15% ;"></th>
              <th style="width: 15% ;">Price</th>
              <th style="color: white; font: bold 20px Tahoma ; width: 15% ; text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px black, 0 0 25px blue, 0 0 5px darkblue;">HUNGRY !</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td><h5> Margarita Pizza</h5> <p>Mozzarella cheese, pepper, olives, onion and tomatoes</p> </td>
              <td>  <img src="image/m.JPG" alt="Margarita" title="Margarita">  </td>
              <td> <p>small : 20 L.E</p> <P>large : 35 L.E</P> </td>

              <td>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" style="margin: 5px ;" onclick="additem('Margarita Pizza (S)' , 20 );"> Add Small </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success"  id="btnl" onclick="additem('Margarita Pizza (L)', 35 );"> Add Large </button>
              </td> 
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><h5> Cheese Lovers Pizza  </h5> <p>Mix cheese, pepper, olives, onion and tomatoes</p> </td>
              <td>  <img src="image/c.jpg" alt="Cheese Lovers" title="Cheese Lovers">  </td>
              <td> <p>small : 20 L.E</p> <P>large : 35 L.E</P> </td>

              <td>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" style="margin: 5px ;" onclick="additem('Cheese Lovers (S)', 20 );"> Add Small </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success"  id="btnl" onclick="additem('Cheese Lovers (L)', 35 )">Add Large</button>
              </td> 
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><h5> Vegetables Pizza  </h5> <p>Vegetables, pepper, olives, onion, tomatoes and mozzarella cheese</p> </td>
              <td>  <img src="image/v.JPG" alt="Vegetables" title="Vegetables">  </td>
              <td> <p>small : 20 L.E</p> <P>large : 35 L.E</P> </td>

              <td>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" style="margin: 5px ;" onclick="additem('Vegetables Pizza (S)', 20 );"> Add Small </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success"  id="btnl" onclick="additem('Vegetables Pizza (L)', 35 );"> Add Large </button>
              </td> 
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><h5> Meat Pizza  </h5> <p>Meat, pepper, olives, onion, tomatoes and mozzarella cheese</p> </td>
              <td>  <img src="image/meat.JPG" alt="Meat" title="Meat">  </td>
              <td> <p>small : 20 L.E</p> <P>large : 35 L.E</P> </td>

              <td>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" style="margin: 5px ;" onclick="additem('Meat Pizza (S)', 20 ); ">Add Small</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success"  id="btnl" onclick="additem('Meat Pizza (L)', 35 ); ">Add Large</button>
              </td> 
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><h5> Chicken Pizza  </h5> <p>Chicken, chicken pane, pepper, olives, onion, tomatoes and mozzarella cheese</p> </td>
              <td>  <img src="image/ch.png" alt="Chicken" title="Chicken">  </td>
              <td> <p>small : 20 L.E</p> <P>large : 35 L.E</P> </td>

              <td>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" style="margin: 5px ;" onclick="additem('Chicken Pizza (S)', 20 ); ">Add Small</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success"  id="btnl" onclick="additem('Chicken Pizza (L)', 35 ) ;">Add Large</button>
              </td> 
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><h5> Mushroom Pizza  </h5> <p>Mushroom, pepper, olives, onion, tomatoes and mozzarella cheese</p> </td>
              <td>  <img src="image/mu.JPG" alt="Mushroom" title="Mushroom">  </td>
              <td> <p>small : 20 L.E</p> <P>large : 35 L.E</P> </td>

              <td>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" style="margin: 5px ;" onclick="additem('Mushroom Pizza (S)', 20 ) ;"> Add Small </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success"  id="btnl" onclick="additem('Mushroom Pizza (L)', 35 );"> Add Large </button>
              </td> 
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><h5>  Seafood Pizza  </h5> <p>Seafood, pepper, olives, onion, tomatoes and mozzarella cheese</p> </td>
              <td>  <img src="image/s.JPG" alt="Seafood" title="Seafood">  </td>
              <td> <p>small : 20 L.E</p> <P>large : 35 L.E</P> </td>

              <td>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" style="margin: 5px ;" onclick="additem('Seafood Pizza (S)', 20 ) ;">Add Small</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="btnl" onclick="additem('Seafood Pizza (L)', 35 ) ;">Add Large</button>
              </td> 
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md" style="background-color: #D9FFFA; font-size:18px; text-align: left ; margin: 0px 10px 10px 0px" id="order">
      <h1 style="margin-bottom: 10px ; text-align: center ;">Your Order</h1>
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-7" style="margin: 10px 10px;" id="selecteditems">

          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3" style="margin: 8px 10px ;" id="removebtn">

          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</section>
```

and here is Javascript functions :

```
function additem ( name , price ) {
document.getElementById("selecteditems").innerHTML += "<p id='selected"+i+"' >" + name +" :  " + price + " L.E" ;

document.getElementById("removebtn").innerHTML += "<p id='selected"+i+"'>" + "<button id='selected"+i+"' class='btn btn-danger' onclick='removeitem("+i+" , "+price+" ) ' style='font-size: 15px; height: 20px; padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;' >Remove</button> " ;
i++ ;
sum += price ;
}
function removeitem ( i , price ) {
document.getElementById("selected"+i ).innerHTML= "" ;
sum -= price ;
i-- ;
}
```

Comment: Can you put what you have so far in a codepen? It would be a lot easier to help you if I can see exactly what is working and I can help you with the architectural details that way making updates to your code won't be such a pain. Also do you have any API's set up to pull in your data or are you just going with static data for now?

Comment: I threw it in a code pen, but if you get a chance you might want to do the same so other people can help.

Comment: Please share a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Sorry for my late answer but this is only my second post and I am learning how to use the website tools , I have edited the question and inserted snippet

Comment: @Larry Lane no I don't have API I will keep things law level front end for now

Comment: I can understand that, I will post an answer with a place you can start here in a minute and I will add to it address your other points when I get a chance.

Comment: @LarryLane Thanks in advance , and I want to learn how to make database in a way that it will fit what i need in this website, so could you kindly lighten my way and give me some titles to go after

Comment: Yes I can help with that, I will be back on a bit later(going to make dinner) to add some more things to my answer to get you pointed in the right direction.

Comment: @AliZain, Take a look at my update when you get a chance to see if it makes any sense.

Answer (score 0):

This will get you started I recommend using some sort of data structure to begin with so you can update it as necessary in my example I am just using JSON. Please note that the data that I am using is just a small sample of what your menu may look like(you can add details as needed). The goal of for now is to give you an idea of how to update you data in a more dynamic way. You will notice if you click on the example that you top nav will update your menu with out reloading the page. Right now only the first two options are hooked up(you will need to hook up the rest). The value in the data-menu-link attribute in the nav links will have to match a property holding an array of objects contained in the menuData JSON inside the javascript. You can see how that I have added pizza and sandwiches as the first two menu items in the JSON.

Example: https://codepen.io/larryjoelane/pen/oEvZGJ

**HTML:**

Pizza

Sandwiches

Meals

Crepe

Salade

About Us

Choose Items
        
          
            Pizza :

```
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md" style="background-color: #D9FFFA; font-size:18px; text-align: left ; margin: 0px 10px 10px 0px" id="order">
        <h1 style="margin-bottom: 10px ; text-align: center ;">Your Order</h1>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-7" style="margin: 10px 10px;" id="selecteditems">

          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3" style="margin: 8px 10px ;" id="removebtn">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 6rem;
  background-color: black;
}
header ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  margin-left: 6rem;
}
header ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}
header ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  margin: 0 0.5rem;
}
header ul li a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

#menu td {
  padding: 1rem 1rem;
  text-align: center;
}
#menu button {
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  margin: 0.5rem 0.25rem;
  border-radius: 1.5rem;
}

body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 6rem;
  background-color: black;
}
header ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  margin-left: 6rem;
}
header ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}
header ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  margin: 0 0.5rem;
}
header ul li a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

#menu td {
  padding: 1rem 1rem;
  text-align: center;
}
#menu button {
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  margin: 0.5rem 0.25rem;
  border-radius: 1.5rem;
}
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var menuData = {
  "pizza": [
    {
      "Pizza Type": "Margarita Pizza",
      "Toppings": "Mozzarella cheese, pepper, olives, onion and tomatoes",
      "Pricing": "small : 20 L.E large: 35 L.E",
      "HUNGRY !":
        "<button type='button' data-small-price='20'>Add Small</button> <button type='button' data-large-price>Add Large</button>"
    },
    {
      "Pizza Type": "Pepperoni",
      "Toppings": "Mozzarella cheese, pepperoni",
      "Pricing": "small : 18 L.E large: 32 L.E",
      "HUNGRY !":
        "<button type='button' data-small-price='20'>Add Small</button> <button type='button' data-large-price>Add Large</button>"
    }
  ],
  "sandwiches": [
    {
      "Sandwich Type": "Rueben",
      "Description": "smoked corn beef, sauerkraut on marble rye",
      "Pricing": "half : 8 L.E full: 16 L.E",
      "HUNGRY !":
        "<button type='button' data-small-price='8'>Add Small</button> <button type='button' data-large-price='16'>Add Large</button>"
    },
    {
      "Sandwich Type": "Club",
      "Description": "roast beef, turkey, and ham on sourdough",
      "Pricing": "half : 9 L.E full: 15 L.E",
      "HUNGRY !":
        "<button type='button' data-small-price='9'>Add Small</button> <button type='button' data-large-price='15'>Add Large</button>"
    }
  ]
};

var selector = "menu";

/* 
  call the jsonToTable function on page load to 
  display the default menu.
*/

jsonToTable(menuData.pizza, selector);

// register event listener to for menu nav click events
document.querySelector('[data-top-nav]')
  .addEventListener('click', function($event) {
  if ($event.target !== $event.currentTarget) {
    var menu = $event.target.getAttribute('data-menu-link');
    console.log(menuData[menu]);
    // load the correct menu
    jsonToTable(menuData[menu], selector);
  }
  $event.stopPropagation();
});

function jsonToTable(json, selector) {
  //begin function

  //array to hold the html for the table
  var html = [];

  //add the opening table and tablebody tags
  html.push("<table>\n<tbody>");

  //begin adding the table headers
  html.push("<tr>");

  //loop through the property names of the first object
  for (var propertyNames in json[0]) {
    //begin for in loop

    // uncomment if you want to use the propery names as headings
    html.push("<th>" + propertyNames + "</td>");
  } //end for in loop

  html.push("</tr>");

  //loop through the array of objects
  json.forEach(function(item) {
    //begin forEach

    //add the opening table row tag
    html.push("<tr>");

    //loop though each of the objects properties
    for (var key in item) {
      //begin for in loop

      //append the table data containing the objects property value
      html.push("<td>" + item[key] + "</td>");
    } //end for in loop

    //add the closing table row tag
    html.push("</tr>");
  }); //end forEach

  //add the closing table and table body tags
  html.push("<table>\n</tbody>");

  //testing display of results
  document.getElementById(selector).innerHTML = html.join("");
} //end function
```

** I will add more details later **